# Detect Facebook language

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a Facebook application where there will be 2 languages, obviously the user can switch himself, but I would also like to detect what language the user is using on Facebook so I can set that as a default one.

I checked the opengraph API, but there doesn't seem to be any way to detect this, are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is look here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Check locale and languages

Comment: Oh shit, I totally overlooked that, I was confusing it with the location, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Using Graph API:

```
/me?fields=locale
```